# How can I pass a swift Data struct to C code and vice versa?

Tags: c, swift

I am trying to pass a byte array+length to C and since swift is using the existing Data struct to store byte array with the length built into it, I would like to know how to pass a swift Data struct to C complete with a replica Data struct in C

A corollary is how can I also return a Data struct from C to swift?

I have tried to create a corresponding Data struct in the C header file:

```
typedef struct {
    const char *data;
    unsigned int count;
} CData;
```

In my swift code I tried to marshal the the byte content from the swift Data struct to the CData struct:

```
let swiftString = "Swift String"
let testString: [CChar]? = swiftString.cString(using: .utf8)
var data = Data()
data.append(contentsOf: Array(swiftString.utf8))

var cData = UnsafeMutablePointer<CData>.allocate(capacity: 1)
defer {
    cData.deallocate()
}
cData.pointee.count = UInt32(data.count)
cData.pointee.data = UnsafePointer(UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: data.count))
defer {
    cData.pointee.data.deallocate()
}
data.copyBytes(to: cData.pointee.data, count: data.count) // Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<Int8>?' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>'

}
```

However, I get the error 
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer?' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'
when I try to copy the byte content from Data to CData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of UInt8 on the C side would be unsigned char. Therefore your C structure would look more like this:

```
typedef struct {
    const unsigned char *data;
    unsigned int count;
} CData;
```

Then slightly adjust the conversion you show in your question:

```
...
let bytes = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data.count)
cData.pointee.data = UnsafePointer(bytes)
defer {
    cData.pointee.data.deallocate()
}
data.copyBytes(to: bytes, count: data.count)
```

To finally test it, one could define the following on C-side:

```
void transfer_data(CData *data) {
    printf("length: %d\n", data->count);
    for(int i = 0; i < data->count; i++) {
        printf("%c(0x%x) ", data->data[i], data->data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

You could call it inside a C-dylib from Swift like this:

```
typealias transferDataFunc = @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<CData>) -> Void

...
let transfer_data_sym = dlsym(handle, "transfer_data")
let transferData = unsafeBitCast(transfer_data_sym, to: transferDataFunc.self)
transferData(cData)
```

This will output the following to the debug console:

```
length: 12
S(0x53) w(0x77) i(0x69) f(0x66) t(0x74)  (0x20) S(0x53) t(0x74) r(0x72) i(0x69) n(0x6e) g(0x67)
```